# Initialize OpenCVSharp.VideoCapture from Stream

Tags: c#, opencv

In my application in different scenarios I may need to read video from a file or from a memory buffer. I'd like to implement a generic way to process it. Is it possible to initialize VideoCapture class not from a file or a camera, but from System.IO.Stream?